# Learning GR with a PhD in 'Classical' Physics

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I've recently graduated with a PhD in a very classical field of physics - Optical Trapping. From a physics/maths perspective, I haven't had to deal with anything more complicated than Stochastic DEs and certainly haven't touched any interesting theoretical work since undergrad.

I want to get into 'understanding' GR out of personal curiosity - not looking to transition to that field, just shoring up my competence in non-experimental, non-classical fields. Does anyone have any recommended textbooks / lecture series?